# Presenting NavigationController with TabBarViewController can not select index programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, swift5

I am trying to present NavigationController and select second tab in the completion block. My code is:

```
let chatViewController = UITabBarController()
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: chatViewController)

present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: {
    self.visibleViewController = navigationController
    self.visibleViewController?.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1
})
```

Second attempt:

```
let chatViewController = UITabBarController()
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: chatViewController)
navigationController.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1

present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: {
    self.visibleViewController = navigationController
})
```

In both cases tabBarController is nil. How can I switch to different tab?

Comment: You know selecting index will load the controller on `UITabBarController` and then you are presenting it, so what's the purpose of selecting controller after presenting?

Comment: just trying: I tried selecting before presenting, doesn't work either. The UITabBarController is nil

Comment: I am asking why you want to select controller, after presenting?

Comment: Shouldn't you dispatch this on the main thread asyncronously? `DispatchQueue.main.async {...}`

Comment: I have two tabs in it, and need second one to be selected.

Comment: but why after presenting? when user can't see it?

Comment: point is I tried before presenting too. Didn't work either. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: @Async- posted as an answer pls check!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to access `UITabBarController` of `UINavigationController`, but you need to access the very first controller from `UINavigationController` and from there you need to make your `UITabBar` selected like this way:

```
func showTabBarControllerr() {
    let chatViewController = UITabBarController()
    //Note: Make sure you have already added the Controllers in Tabbarcontroller
    chatViewController.viewControllers = [DemoOne(), DemoTwo()]
    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: chatViewController)
    present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: {
        if let tabBarController = navigationController.viewControllers.first as? UITabBarController {
            tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1
        }
    })
}
```

Let me know this helps or not!

Comment: I am actually using viewControllers of the chat view controller, but it is made with a factory and passed back here (I simplified question snippet for obvious reasons). How can I access `chatViewController.viewControllers` here?

Comment: @Async- I have assigned that because I am creating `UIViewController`'s programatically. In case, if your "ChatViewController" consisting of controllers then you don't need to assign that! You can Skip that line.

Comment: it is more complex because I use factories, but I think generally your answer is right.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calling

`present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: { })`

in `viewDidLoad`, try to call it in `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear`

Answer (score 0):

Try this (Swift 5):

1. Set an identifier to your UITabBarController in the Storyboard, something like `MainTabBar`
2. Into a function or IBAction, use this code:

   let tbc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainTabBar") as! UITabBarController

   tbc.selectedIndex = 1 // This is the index of your controller

   present(tbc, animated: false, completion: nil)